# How to make a curved view on Android?

Tags: android, layout, view, imageview, slideshow

[image: AirAsia App Reference]

I've found an inspiration of UI from this AirAsia app.
What I'd to do is to create curved imageview, how to do that on Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of libraries for that. Here's one: https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView